# Save json response and parse it into swift object

Tags: json, swift, parsing, alamofire, swifty-json

Hey I am programming a swift app and I consume a rest service for my data. 
I consume it like this:

```
static func findAll() {
    let URL = baseURL + "api/person"

    Alamofire.request(URL).responseJSON {
        response in
        print(response.result.value ?? "")
    }
}
```

This is the json that is returned:

```
{
    Email = "meineEmail@gmail.com";
    Geburtsdatum = "0001-01-01T00:00:00";
    Nachname = Gnadlinger;
    Password = "<null>";
    PersonId = 0;
    Telefonnummer = 9832742;
    Username = SonnyBlackzz;
    Vorname = Johannes;
}
```

Is there a way to save these json values and parse them into an object?

Best regards!

Comment: This is **not** JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create an object eg:

```
struct Person {

   var username: String
   var email: String

   init(username: String, email: String) {
       self.username = username
       self.email = email
   }
}
```

And when you get your data just do this:

```
Alamofire.request(URL).responseJSON {
        response in

     let json = response.result.value

     guard let json != nil else {
          return
     }

     let newPerson = Person(username: json["username"], email: json["email"])
}
```

Comment: I see that you tag swifty-json, is a usefull library to handle json, but this code should work